# What will happen if 1/0 condition appears in microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, avr

I need to implement the following function in a microcontroller:
\begin{equation}
\ k= (v_{(n)} - v_{(n-1)})^{-3}
\end{equation}
Here, 'v' stands for signal amplitude and 'n' for sample number. If the difference bettwen two successive samples becomes zero, what will happen?
Will the corresponding data register will be saturated or it will create junk value or create any problem?

Comment: This cannot be answered without identifying a specific microcontroller, and your tags identify multiple possible architectures. The easiest way to find out is to either look at the datasheet/programmers' guide, or to just try it and see. Beware of performance on microcontrollers that lack hardware dividers.

Comment: Floating point hardware should return a a saturated (either positive or negative infinite) result. FP hardware has an IEEE standard but not all functionality is always implemented.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with electrical engineering – it's about the math / the arithmetic model of the programming language / assembler you're using. If anywhere, it would be on-topic on StackOverflow.com, but there, the question "what happens if I try to divide by 0" certainly would be marked duplicate within minutes.

Comment: It should depend on the microcontroller. For a STM32L476RG, by default, 0 division returns 0. You must set a bit in SCB->CCR to trap it as explained in cortex M4 STM32 programming manual : https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/dm00046982-stm32-cortex-m4-mcus-and-mpus-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I have tested it in Proteus using ATMEGA16. Maybe, AVR register gets saturated. I'll also check the STM. Sometimes simulation shows a result that doesn't happen in practice. So I asked here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I didn't know that StackOverflow has STM & AVR tags.

Comment: Yes, simulation can be different from H/W in these corner cases. Always test & check for the specific device + library. And for portability best to avoid it altogether by checking the denom, as Marko pointed out.

Comment: @SadatRafi a) they do, probably, since STM isn't your architecture (ARM/Thumb v2 is), and b) doesn't make the question an electrical engineering question.

Comment: @SadatRafi The atmega16 doesn't have a hardware divider, so what happens up to the implementation your C compiler uses. (This applies both to integer and floating point division.)

Comment: is this an stm32 or is this an avr, please pick one, or explain.  in either case if fixed point you can do a comparison if floating point you cant directly but can get close enough but have not provided remotely enough information to answer that use case.  Or you can let the divide by zero happen and the soft/hard float is supposed to handle that, the expected is a properly signed infinity, but using a trap is also a legal solution.

Comment: fixed point is generally easier and problems like this become trivial.

Comment: **Why** do you need to implement a function that blows up with a constant input? This implies to me that you need to reformat the problem so that this never happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what architecture you use, you can do a check before dividing.

```
temp = (v(n) - v(n-1));
 if  temp <> 0.0 
{
  result = 1.0/ temp^3 ;
}
else
{
  result = ...whatever you want
}
```

Comment: an equals test if that is what this is will only work with fixed point, if this is floating point 1) dont do float on an mcu 2) you cant trust equals tests.

Comment: I agree on where testing floats to be equal will not work, but for not using floats on MCU does not apply here. With small 8 bit MCUs like AVRs, the float library can exceed the flash memory size easily, and it does not make much sense to use floats. The OP is using a 32-bit STM32 ARM which can handle occasional floats just fine, and higher end models come with built in FPU. It does not make sense to avoid floats in that case.